# Integral of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Why is $$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{|x|}} < \infty?$$

The area seems infinite since there is an asymptote at $0$.
Can someone explain? Thanks

Comment: Hint: $$ \int dx \, x^{-1/2} = 2 x^{1/2}+C$$

Comment: But why is there no correspondence the graphic area?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this reasoning will be convincing:  A change of variables merely re-arranges the area under a curve, it does not change the area.  So let's try
$$
x = u^2
$$
and look at $\int_0^1 \frac1{\sqrt{x}}\, dx$.
By coincidence, when $x=0$ $u=0$ and when $x=1$, $u=1$.

If $x = u^2$ then $dx = 2u\, du$ so the integral becomes
$$
\int_{u=0}^1 \frac{2u\, du}{u} = \int_{u=0}^1 2 du = 2 
$$
OUr change of variables has transformed an ugly chimney into a nice box.

Comment: this is a very nice answer (+1)

Comment: Very interesting! Thanks!!

Comment: The thing is I have to solve integrals of the type (1/(1-f(x))^2, but I guess there's no 'standard' trick to see if it converges or not, right?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may observe that
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}\:dx&=2\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}\:dx
\\\\&=2\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\:dx
\\\\&=4\left[\sqrt{x}\right]_0^1 
\\\\&=4.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: this is hardly a hint...

Comment: @gt6989b In fact, I'm not sure I'm answering the 'why' part of the OP question, hence my caution...

Comment: But why is there no correspondence  the graphic area?

Comment: @Elle One can not always know if an area under an infinite curve is finite or not just by looking at it... The antiderivative might help in these cases.

Comment: What if the integral cannot be easily calculated? Is there no way to know if the integral of 1/(1-f (x)) is convergent?

Comment: You are right, If the integral can not be easily evaluated, one may try to use some dominated values to obtain a convergent result... if this is the case.

Comment: Can you show an example? Thank you!!

Comment: Sure. For example, there is no elementary antiderivative for $\frac{\sin(x^3+ax+7)}{\sqrt{x}}$ but one has $$\left|\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(x^3+ax+7)}{\sqrt{x}} dx\right|\le  \int_0^\pi \frac{\left|\sin(x^3+ax+7)\right|}{\sqrt{x}} dx\le  \int_0^\pi \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} dx=2\sqrt{\pi}.$$ You are welcome.

Comment: To apply the fundamental theorem of calculus, we need $f$ to be Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$.  $x^{- \frac 12}$ is not bounded on $[0,1]$ hence not Riemann integrable. The trick is to take the integral from $[\epsilon, 1]$ and let $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Yes, this is an improper integral.

Comment: @Oliver Ok, very clear, thanks! The thing is I have to solve integrals of the type (1/(1-f(x))^2, but I guess there's no 'standard' domination to tell if it converges or not, right?

Answer (score 0):

The integrand is even so sufficient to show on the interval $[0,1]$. We have
$$
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt x} = \int x^{-1/2} dx = \frac{x^{1/2}}{1/2} = 2\sqrt{x},
$$
which easily evaluates both at $0$ and and $1$...

Comment: But why is there no correspondence the graphic area?

Answer (score 0):

Let's restrict attention to the interval $[0, 1]$.  (The situation in $[-1, 0]$ is symmetric.)  If we try to compute
$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow 0+} \int_{t}^{1} {dx \over \sqrt{x}},
$$
we see that, for each $t$ the antiderivative turns out to be
$$
(-1) \sqrt{x}\; \big|^{1}_{t} = (-1) (1 - \sqrt{t}),
$$
which has a right-sided limit at $t = 0$.  The existence of the limit tells that the integral converges.